# Geotagging with Photos or other app

Tags: photos.app, geolocation, adobe-lightroom, image-processing

I've got ~100GB of photos that I've imported into Photos. Photos stayed in place because they are in date related subfolders. I would stay with original sorting as it is more usable with other photo apps.

I decided to add geocoding to photos manually (without gpx track). Photos app does its job. I also rotated couple of the photos (my old camera doesn't have orientation sensor). So I would like to save back changes to original photos (overwrite them).
The problem is that I'm not able to export photos into the same directory structure that I've used originally. So it is a real pain to export than overwrite images manually. Other issue is that I will lost the original file dates of the photos (Photo app creates file with current date).

Is there any app that able to hand this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HoudahGeo](https://www.houdah.com/houdahGeo/) to write location information back into the original image files.

1. Using the media browser in HoudahGeo, add the photos to a new project
2. HoudahGeo will ask about camera clock settings. Click OK, you don’t need accurate timestamps for this procedure
3. Select EXIF/XMP export from the Output menu
4. Use the following settings:

   - Uncheck “Selected images only”
   - Check “Geotagged images only”
   - Tag: “Original images”
   - Uncheck “Create copies”. Be sure to have a backup
   - XMP Sidecars: “Write to sidecar if present”
   - Uncheck “Notify media library”
   - Select Coordinates and other properties you want to export
   - Be sure NOT to export timestamp. You did not give HoudahGeo accurate information on the camera clock setup

Full disclosure: I am the developer of HoudahGeo.